# Unir dos arrays en uno JAVA

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, bucles

Buenas estoy intentando meter dos arrays dentro de uno y me sale el siguiente error;

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 20 out of bounds for length 20

Soy nuevo programando en java dado a eso he estado mirando en bastantes sitios pero la verdad es que no encuentro una solución por si alguien podría ayudar. A continuación dejo el código. //El problema digamos que partiría del "Ejercicio 3".

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*Crea un programa con dos arrays de tamaño 20 y otro de tamaño 40
     El primer array lo llenaremos con numeros aleatorios entre el 0 y el 20
     el segundo array será la copia inversa del primer array
     el terter array está formado por los dos primeros que sería la primera mitad del 
     array 1 y la segunda mitad el array2*/

    int array1[] = new int[20];
    int array2[] = new int[20];
    int array3[] = new int [(20+20)-1];
    int array4[] = new int[40];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        int valorAleatorio = (int)(Math.random() * (20+1)); 
        array1[i] = valorAleatorio;
    }
    
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("*************************");
    System.out.println("Ejercicio 1");
    System.out.println("*************************");
    System.out.println("");
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < array1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Array[" + i + "] = " + array1[i]);
    }
    
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("*************************");
    System.out.println("Ejercicio 2");
    System.out.println("*************************");
    System.out.println("");
    
    int j=array2.length-1;
    
    for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
        array2[i] = array1[j];
        System.out.println("Array2[" + i + "] = " + array2[i] + " <-- Array1[" + (j) + "] = " + array1[j]);
        j--;
    
    }
    
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("*************************");
    System.out.println("Ejercicio 3");
    System.out.println("*************************");
    System.out.println("");

    for(int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++){
        array3[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
        System.out.println("Array3[" + i + "] = " + array3[i] + " <-- Array1[" +i+ "] = " + array1[i]);
        System.out.println("Array3[" + (i) + "] = " + array3[(i)] + " <-- Array2[" +i+ "] = " + array2[i]);

    }   

}
```

Comment: el problema es que array 3 tiene 39 elementos, y array1 y 2 tienen 20.. entonces si recorres basado en array3, hay indices que no existen....

Comment: Vale lo que he hecho ha sido lo siguiente y me sigue dando error;

he modificado la variable array3;

`int array3[] = new int [40];`
------------

Luego he modificado los Sysout;

`System.out.println("Array3[" + i + "] = " + array3[i] + " <-- Array1[" +i+ "] = " + array1[i]);`
`System.out.println("Array3[" + (i+19) + "] = " + array3[(i+19)] + " <-- Array2[" +i+ "] = " + array2[i]);`
------------------------------
y me sigue dando el mismo error
@gbianchi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema del error que te salta es que intentas acceder a elementos del array1 y array2 que no existen.
Esto lo haces a la hora de hacer el el for tomando como referencia el tamaño del array3 (39) e intentas obtener valores de los array1 y array2 que tienen tamaño (20)

---

(EDITADO)
Una vez vista tu aclaración he modificado el código para que sea como dices:
Y por cierto a la hora de declara el tamaño del array3 mejor hazlo así:`int array3[] = new int [array1.length + array2.length];` Así te ahorras problemas con el tamaño. Porque otro problema que ibas a tener si ponías solo `int array3[] = new int [39];` era que no ibas a poder acceder al array3[39], que lo necesitas si quieres meter los 40 elementos del array1 y array2, esto se debe que el array empieza a contar del 0 al 39-1 y te saltaria otra vez el mismo error.

```
 int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++){
        if(i<array1.length) { 
            array3[i] = array1[i];
            System.out.println("Array3[" + i + "] = " + array3[i] + " <-- Array1[" +i+ "] = " + array1[i]);
        }else {
            array3[i] = array2[k]; 
            System.out.println("Array3[" + i + "] = " + array3[i] + " <-- Array2[" +k+ "] = " + array2[k]);
            k++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por responder, ha sido culpa mía lo había escrito mal ya que la primera mitad (20) sería el array 1 y la segunda mitad(20) sería el array 2, me refería a eso. 
Sin embargo me sigue dando error aunque aumente el tamaño del array. Al llegar a 20 no sigue hasta, se repite 2 veces el "array1" digamos que no llega a coger el segundo array dentro del 3 y a todo esto me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta con la corrección gracias a tu aclaración

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Tengo una duda más. Si por ejemplo en vez de ordenarlos quisiera hacer que se rellenase del Array3[i] hasta el 40 con numeros del array1 y array2 aleatoriamente que se debería hacer?

Comment: Se me ocurre que necesitarías dos variables random, una que cambie entre 0 y 1 y la otra de 0 a 19, la primera te escoge entre el array1 y array2 y la segunda te dice el valor que escoger del array. El esquema seria el siguiente:
for(int i=0;i,arra3.length; i++)
variable1.random
variable2.random
if(variable1==0) array3[i] =array1[variable2]
else array3[i]=array2[variable2]